# Como chamar uma função externa, sem enviar o 'self'?

Tags: python

Eu estou usando um atributo de classe pra guardar a View que eu quero testar numa aplicação Django, assim:

```py
# TESTS.PY
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    _VIEW = views.order

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        self._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})


# VIEWS.PY
def order(request, sku)
     ...
```

Mas durante a execução, como eu chamo um atributo do meu objeto `OrderTests` o Python envia `self` como argumento, o que não bate com a assinatura da função `order` e causa todo tipo de problemas.

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o Python não envie o `self` nesse caso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O ideal é usar o decorador [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) do Python na declaração do atributo `_VIEW`. Afinal de contas, o que você quer é acessá-lo de forma estática (independente da instância da classe de testes `OrderTests`).

```
# TESTS.PY
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    _VIEW = staticmethod(views.order)

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        self._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})


# VIEWS.PY
def order(request, sku)
     ...
```

Answer (score 7):

> **Nota**: essa resposta indica um modo alternativo de fazer *unbinding* num método *bounded*, que pode ser útil em algumas situações, mas existem maneiras melhores de resolver a pergunta original. Ver [a resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3825/215) para uma solução preferível a esta.

Você pode usar a propriedade `__func__` do seu método (`im_func`, se Python <2.6):

```py
>>> OrderTests()._VIEW
<bound method OrderTests.order of <__main__.OrderTests object at 0x00BFA090>>
>>> OrderTests()._VIEW.__func__
<function order at 0x00BFE170>
```

Quando se acessa um método através da sintaxe `objeto.método` o resultado é um `bound method`, que já está ligado ao objeto de origem (i.e. ele atribui o `self` para você, e você o chama passando um argumento posicional a menos). Chamando-se `__func__` você tem uma referência para a função original, de modo que é necessário passar o `self` explicitamente. (quando há um `self`, é claro - já que isso é apenas uma convenção; no seu caso, o primeiro argumento para `order` é, de fato, o próprio `request`)

```py
self._VIEW.__func__(request, **{'sku': order.sku})
```

Fonte (em inglês) [aqui](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), procure por "User-defined methods".

Comment: Isso funciona, mas é bem longe de ser o modo certo.  Se você se deu ao trabalho de colocar um membro da classe por que quer reutilizar o mesmo em vários casos de teste, ele precisa ser um callable genérico. Se for um objeto que você tem que chamar o atributo `__func__`, e amanhã esse  `_VIEW` é trocado pra outra coisa, tem que mexer nos métodos.

Comment: @jsbueno Concordo. Deixei uma nota no início da resposta esclarecendo esse ponto.

Answer (score 3):

Em Python você pode chamar um método ou propriedade de dentro de uma classe de dois modos, mas antes considere a seguinte classe:

```python
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome = "nenhum"):
        self.nome = nome

    def set_nome(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def get_nome(self):
        return self.nome
```

**- Passando o objeto para a classe ao chamar o método:**

```python
amigos = [Pessoa("Lucas"), Pessoa("Julia"), Pessoa("Bruna")]

for amigo in amigos:
    print(Pessoa.get_nome(amigo))
```

Nesse método você utiliza a classe para chamar os métodos e propriedades, mas o primeiro argumento deve ser um objeto dessa classe, pois ela precisa retirar essas informações de algum lugar. Eu geralmente utilizo esse método quando tenho uma lista de objetos do mesmo tipo, pois ele facilita o acesso aos métodos e propriedades, aparentemente ao ler sua pergunta tive a impressão que utilizou essa forma.

**- Chamando o método através do objeto:**

```python
maria = Pessoa("Maria")

print(maria.get_nome())
```

Esse método é o mais utilizado e é muito parecido com o que acontece em linguagens orientadas a objeto como Java e C#. Para que o "o Python não envie o `self`" como descrito na sua pergunta, você precisa utilizar este método. Apenas uma correção, você disse que `order` é uma função, se `order` está pedindo como primeiro argumento `self` quer dizer que ele está contido em uma classe, então ele não é chamado de "função" e sim "método".

Comment: Acho que você interpretou mal a pergunta... `order` não é método de um objeto, ele é de fato uma função isolada. O problema é que a referência para essa função está guardada em uma classe, de modo que a chamada da mesma (por meio da segunda forma apresentada na sua resposta) está incorretamente atribuindo o `self`, quando o que o OP quer é que isso não ocorra. Veja minha resposta para uma solução possível (pode haver outras)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode só fazer um wrapper da função que você quer testar.

```
# TESTS.PY
class OrderTests(TestCase, ShopTest):
    def _VIEW(self, *args, **kwargs):
        views.order(*args, **kwargs)

    def test_gateway_answer(self):
        url = 'whatever url'
        request = self.request_factory(url, 'GET')
        self._VIEW(request, **{'sku': order.sku})


# VIEWS.PY
def order(request, sku)
     ...
```

É uma linha a mais de código, mas deixa bem claro o que você está fazendo.