# Há alguma vantagem num "self" explícito em vez do "this" implícito?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, funções, design-de-linguagem

Ao contrário da maioria das linguagens [mais populares] orientadas por objeto, que usam uma palavra-chave para se referir ao objeto que é "alvo" de uma chamada de método (normalmente denominado `this`), a linguagem Python exige que todo método possua um parâmetro adicional (o primeiro, e por convenção usualmente chamado `self`) para representar esse objeto. Isso me parece um caso de [código *boilerplate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code), que você tem de escrever sempre mas que não acrescenta muita coisa...

(Nota: esse é um caso particular do uso de "pronomes" no código, algo [possível na linguagem Lisp](http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_18.html) e [usado extensivamente na linguagem Perl](http://www.kichwa.com/quik_ref/spec_variables.html))

Há alguma razão concreta para **não se usar** um `this` implícito [no design de uma linguagem de propósito geral ou [DSL]](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico)? Algum caso de uso em que o parâmetro explícito permite/facilita algo que seria inviável caso ele fosse implícito?

Observações:

- Mesmo em Python, se você obtém uma referência para um método de um objeto ele vem como um `bound method`, e você o chama omitindo o primeiro argumento:

  ```python
  class Foo(object):
      def bar(self, a, b):
          return self.x + a + b

  foo = Foo()
  bar = foo.bar
  bar(10, 20) # 10 é "a" e 20 é "b"; o "self" já está atribuído para você
  ```

  ...sendo necessário o uso de [uma função especial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1517/215) para se "reatribuir" o mesmo a um objeto diferente:

  ```python
  foo2 = Foo()
  bar.__func__(foo2, 10, 20)
  ```
- Nada impede que uma função "normal" seja transformada num método através de uma operação semelhante ao [*currying*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21215/215):

  ```python
  def encadear(a, b):
      a.proximo = b

  class Foo(object):
      append   = lambda self, b: encadear(self, b)
      appendTo = lambda self, a: encadear(a, self)
  ```

  (através de uma sintaxe mais amigável, claro... e nesse caso, proibir o uso do `this` em funções declaradas fora do contexto de um objeto seria desejável - ao contrário do que ocorre com JavaScript por exemplo)
- ...ou que um método seja transformado numa função normal através de uma operação inversa:

  ```js
  var foo = {
      bar:function(a, b) {
          return this.x + a + b;
      }
  };

  var bar = foo.bar;
  var foo2 = { x:10 };
  bar.call(foo2, 20, 30); // O método original mantém o this explícito,
                          // mas ainda podemos atribuí-lo explicitamente
  ```

Diante disso, não vejo razão para se explicitar o `self`, apenas código desnecessário... Há algum argumento forte a favor, talvez vindo do(s) próprio(s) autor(es) da linguagem Python? (ou de outra linguagem que use estratégia semelhante)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das vantagens de usar self explícito é que você simplifica a linguagem:

- Com self explícito o escopo do self vai ser um escopo léxico igual ao de todas as outras variáveis. Não precisa criar uma regra de escopo separada só pro self.
- Com self explícito, métodos e funções são a mesma coisa. Com self implícito, funções e métodos se comportam de forma diferente.
- Com self explícito, é mais fácil saber como chamar o método de um objeto com o self de outro objeto (basta passar outro valor no primeiro parâmetro). Em linguagens com o self mais mágico é preciso chamar a função de forma especial: em Javascript vc tem que usar `call`, em Python vc vai ter que tomar cuidado pra não criar um bound method, etc.

UM exemplo que eu acho que vale a pena adicionar a discussão é o da linguagem Lua. Lá objetos são meio que hash tables e métodos são simplesmente propriedades dae um objeto que por acaso são uma função (similarmente a Javascript). Diferentemente de Javascript, não existe mágica para setar o self: por convenção , você deve chamar o método passando o próprio objeto como primeiro parâmetro.

```lua
local my_obj = {}
my_obj.x
my_obj.my_method = function(self)
  print(self.x)
end

my_obj.my_method(my_obj)
```

A desvantagem do self explíito é a verbosidade dessa convenção mas pode ser mais simples resolver isso com um pouco de açúcar sintático do que alterando as regras básicas da linguagem. Por exemplo, em Lua exístes alguns acúcares sintáticos envolvendo o `:`:

```lua
-- Esse código vai ser desassucarado pra algo parecido
-- com o exemplo anterior

local my_obj = {}
my_obj.x = 17
function my_obj:my_method()
  -- Aqui o `:` insere um parâmetro self no começo da lista de parâmetros
  return self.x
end

-- Aqui o `:` passa o objeto como primeiro parâmetro na chamada
-- da função.
my_obj:mymethod()
```

Comment: É um ótimo exemplo, não conheço a linguagem Lua mas pelo que mostrou aqui ela é mais "sã" que Python e JavaScript. Esse açúcar sintático que você mencionou é bastante semelhante a fazer um *currying* no primeiro argumento. Só me parece que, quando se usa o `:`, o escopo léxico do `self` se torna tão problemático quando o do `this` implícito, não? Pense em um closure onde tanto a função *outer* quanto a *inner* use esse açúcar sintático (se isso for suportado por Lua é claro): nesse caso vai haver *capture* do nome `self` na interna, que nem o problema do `var that = this` no JavaScript.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: O `:` é só um açúcar sintático (abreviação) que é completamente equivalente a se você tivesse escrito um parâmetro chamado `self` na mão. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.4.10

Comment: Hehe eu entendi! O que estou dizendo é que seu uso o torna tão passível de um *capture* quanto um `self` implícito (i.e. equivalente a se você tivesse escrito um parâmetro chamado `self` na mão em **ambas** as funções interna e externa). Mas eu concordo que há vantagem nesse caso: o programador sempre tem a opção de **não usar** o açúcar sintático sempre que o mesmo for causar problemas...

Comment: @mgibsonbr: A função de dentro não vai declarar um parâmetro self próprio então não vai ocorrer shadowing. Ao contrário de Javascript, a declaração do self só ocorre se você escrever ela explicitamente (com um parâmetro explícito ou com `:`).

Answer (score 5):

Na minha opinião a maior vantagem do self explícito é viabilizar "closures" sem pegadinhas e sem tratamento especial. De cara evita aquele problema em que todo iniciante Javascript cai:

```
Objeto.prototype.metodo = function ()
{
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.bla(); // errado, this será window
        self.bla(); // correto
    }, 250);
}
```

Em Python o equivalente seria mais ou menos:

```
class Objeto:
 def metodo(self):
  def closure():
   self.bla()
  glib.timeout_add(250, closure)
```

Não há ambiguidade com o 'self' explícito, enquanto um 'self' implícito poderia ser bastante confuso no caso de haver mais aninhamento de métodos.

Comment: Entendo o que quer dizer... Com o `self` explícito fica fácil evitar *erasure* do nome - basta dar um nome diferente dentro do closure - enquanto um implícito ia ter conflito **sempre**. É um bom argumento.

Comment: Correção: fica fácil evitar ***capture*** do nome.

Answer (score 4):

Certamente seria possível que o `self` fosse um parâmetro implícito, como o `this` de outras linguagens, mas acredito que seja assim porque uma das filosofias de Python é deixar as coisas explícitas.

Dentro de uma classe Python, a diferença entre um método com e um sem o `self` é praticamente a mesma entre um método normal e um método estático em linguagens como C++ e Java. Em C++ e Java o `this` é um parâmetro implícito nos métodos normais, e você tem que marcar o método como `static` caso queira um método estático. No Python isso fica completamente escancarado.

Isso também obriga você a qualificar o acesso aos atributos da classe. Em C++ e Java, se você vê uma variável no meio de um método você não sabe se ela é membro da classe ou não. Você pode qualificar com o `this` pra deixar isso explícito, mas é opcional. Em Python isso sempre é explícito por design.

Comment: Em suma... a vantagem do "self" explícito é o fato de ser explícito!

Comment: "Você pode qualificar com o `this` pra deixar isso explícito, mas é opcional" em Java e C++ sim, mas em JavaScript não... É possível ter ambos: `this` implícito e `this.membro` obrigatoriamente explícito. Quanto ao uso do `static`, é um bom argumento, embora mesmo em Python não dê para se criar um método estático sem o decorador `@staticmethod` (ou `@classmethod`, mas aí também precisa de um primeiro parâmetro `self` ou `cls`). Se você tentar chamar um método "de instância" via `Classe.metodo` sem passar como primeiro argumento uma instância da classe, dá erro (o que é uma coisa boa aliás).